# In sql, what is the best way to store several ordered vectors/lists?

Tags: c#, sql, list, sql-server-2012

I have a few integer lists of different length of which I want to preserve the order.
I will be using them as alternative to each other, never 2 at the same time.
The number of lists might grow in the future, although I expect it never to reach a value like 50 or so. I might want to insert one value within this list. These lists are relatively seldom modified, and using a manual editor like MS SQL Server Management Studio for this purpose is fine. For what I can see in this moment, these lists will be rarely used to directly make queries, there will be some C# in between.

For storing one ordered list, a linked (or double-linked) list seems appropriate. But if I have to store several ordered lists, it seems to me that I will have to add one table for each one of them. The same is valid if I use an indexed list. On the other hand, I could also store all these lists in one table transforming them in strings (one string per list) with values comma separated, that I would then parse in my C# program.

In sql, what is the best way to store several ordered vectors/lists in sql?

Comment: I would use two tables - list 'headers' and elements, containing header ID and link to next element (or sequence number - depend on your list usage and retrieval scenarios).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Relational databases like SQL Server typically don't have "arrays" or "lists" - if you need to store more than one value - they have **tables** for that. And no - it's in no way *cumbersome* for a database like SQL Server to have even **thousands** of tables - if you really must.....  After all - handling tables is the **core competency** of a relational database ... it should be good at it! (and SQL Server is - and so are many other mature RDBMS systems, too).

And I would ***strongly recommend*** not to use comma-separated strings - those first of all violate even the first normal form of database design, and as soon as you *do need* to join those values against something else - you're in trouble. Don't do this - there's absolutely no need for this, and you'll just make your developer life miserable sometime in the future - if you have the opportunity to avoid it - **don't do it!**

Comment: I tend to agree with you. However, one problem I see is that apparently tables cannot be organized in hierarchies. In the view that I have of my database, I would have "informative" tables mixed up with my vector tables, which will look all alike. I could example add a "zz_" prefix to the name to have them at the end of the list of my tables, but it doesn't seem a clean approach.

Comment: @Antonio What's not "informative" about those tables? Storing information is sort of their thing.

Comment: @Martijn Let's put it in this way: if I could, I would naturally put them all in a subfolder

Comment: @Antonio - if it's just one level of "hierarchy" then you might consider using a different *schema* to separate these tables away from the other tables.

Answer (score 3):

A kind of this?

```
ListId   ItemOrder ItemValue
1        1         10
1        4         7
1        2         5
2        1         55
1        7         23
2        4         15

Select ItemValue FROM [Table] WHERE ListId = 1 Order By ItemOrder
```

Here Each list has an ID (you can use a clustered index here) and the order is given by the field ItemOrder

Comment: I thought about that, I was curious to see how popular would be such an option, let's see... :)

Comment: I use lists of lists like this all the time - far more compact and natural than having a lot of anonymous tables.